# use of import_module in Python

Tags: python, import-module

I'm trying to use import_module in Python 3.4.

The file I want to import contains functions that assumed that numpy as been imported as np. In my master file, I've set this, but it is not loaded with the file.

In the documentation it's written:

Help on function import_module in module importlib:

import_module(name, package=None)
    Import a module.

```
The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
relative import to an absolute import.
```

The documentation tells that the package option is required, but it remains unclear for me how to use it. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The package option is *not* required, and would be used to indicate the package that the module you're importing is from.  The best way would be to import numpy in your module that is being imported, or use the raw `__import__` function with the appropriate globals being passed in

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the option. Thank you for your answer !